# Visual Studio: Pop-up to show implemented interfaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio 2017 so when pointing at a class it shows the interface it implements?

Seeing the exception it throws is very helpful, but it would be nice to see the interfaces as well.

[image]

Comment: place a cursor on your class and press `F12`

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I am aware of the `F12` magic. But I am really looking for this information in a popup

Comment: Not a popup, but shown without navigation: peek definition (Alt-F12) will show the definition.